# How do I have a button appear then disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea how this works. I need a buttons to appear after I hit Start on a button in my blocks. After they appear I also need they to disappear after I click them? Anyone know. If you do it would be Appreciated.
ALL THE CODE HERE.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html><title>Pyramid Rounds!</title>
<body bgcolor=darkblue>
<head>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
    .pyramid, .pyramid .row, .pyramid .row *, .pyramid .block, .pyramid 
.row1 .block, .pyramid .row2 .block, .pyramid .row3 .block, .pyramid .row4 
.block {
    z-index: 1;
    }
.pyramid {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.pyramid .row:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 1;
}
.pyramid .row {
    font-size: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.pyramid .row * {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.pyramid .block {
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 13%;
}
.pyramid .row1 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.pyramid .row2 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.pyramid .row3 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.pyramid .row4 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
</style>
</head>
<img src="pyramidimage.png">
<div class="pyramid">
<div class="row row1">
    <div class="block">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row row3">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row row4">
    <br>
    <div class="button">Start!</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Was wondering if this could be a function or some css? Because it it could be simple and easy to understand ( for learning purposes) it would be great!

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript here. The easiest approach here is to toggle a display class on a click event. CSS and JavaScript are great tools for doing that.

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do. I know JavaScript but not how to make it.

Comment: This is not a valid HTML. body is before head, both as no ending. c'est n'importe quoi! => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#Anatomy_of_a_HTML_document

Comment: I just cut that out cuz it wasn't important lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the function of Javascript and getting the ID of div and checking the style display and changing every time you hit the clicked. From `display:block` to `display:none` and vise versa

You can do like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: It works but is there a way to make them disappearing by clicking the button not start?

Comment: what do you mean? if you click the "not start button" what do you want to disappear?

Comment: Like I want the start button to make all of them appear but to make them disappear I want to click the buttons one by one

Comment: if its not dynamic. You may add an ID to each blocks and do it like the function we did, so every time you click the one block it will hide.

Comment: I'm having trouble with that right now.

Comment: You can ask another question so we can help you, I think that is different problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190334/discussion-between-justinmontalban-and-easton-antony).

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample, i use `show/hide` method and a class `.sure{display:none;}`

```js
$("#start").click(function(){
  $('.sure').show();
})

$(".sure").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
$("#start").hide(); // if you need hide all button
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html><title>Pyramid Rounds!</title>
<body bgcolor=darkblue>
<head>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
    .pyramid, .pyramid .row, .pyramid .row *, .pyramid .block, .pyramid 
.row1 .block, .pyramid .row2 .block, .pyramid .row3 .block, .pyramid .row4 
.block {
    z-index: 1;
    }
.pyramid {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.pyramid .row:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 1;
}
.pyramid .row {
    font-size: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.pyramid .row * {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.pyramid .block {
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 13%;
}
.pyramid .row1 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.pyramid .row2 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.pyramid .row3 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.pyramid .row4 .block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0%;
}

.sure{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<img src="pyramidimage.png">
<div class="pyramid">
<div class="row row1">
    <div class="block">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row row3">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row row4">
    <br>
    <div class="button" id="start">Start!</div>
    <br>
    <button class="button sure">Are you sure?</button>
</div>
</div>
```